# Catching kill signals to Airflow Dags

Tags: python, airflow

tl;dr

A custom operator executes another sub-process (devops pipe) that runs for a while. If the task gets interrupted manually now, the sub-process is still up and running.
Is there a possibility to catch the signal, and then hand it over to the sub-process as well?

---

A trigger executes an Azure Devops pipeline, done through a custom operator class. It runs a post-requests to start the pipe and then waits (pokes) for it to finish.

If the dag or task is killed in the meantime (User interrupting the process in the UI), the Azure pipe still runs without being canceled.
My solution so far would be to write an async. function that checks if the Dag (task) is still available (or got deleted).

Though, a rather native Airflow solution would be more welcome.

Note: I use 1.10.15 and cannot bump to 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your Custom Operator should override `on_kill` method from BaseOperator:

```
    def on_kill(self) -> None:
        """
        Override this method to cleanup subprocesses when a task instance
        gets killed. Any use of the threading, subprocess or multiprocessing
        module within an operator needs to be cleaned up or it will leave
        ghost processes behind.
        """
```

It was always there - even in Airflow 1.10

Comment: .. wow, I really overlooked that, my bad. Will mark the answer once I have implemented it. Thanks for sharing.